# Serial spam about ComTrace

Tags: support, stack-overflow, spam

All 11 of [armecos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281761/armecos)'s answers are promoting a single product named ComTrace.  He very rarely addresses any specific concerns from the questions.  (The closest I see is that "No pay no gain" could be responding to ["Must be free"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461794/whats-a-good-free-serial-port-monitor-for-reverse-engineering).)  There's probably a language barrier.

Are the diamond moderators aware of this serial spammer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just started seeing some flags. I've removed all of his answers and suspended him for one day. Let us know if the behavior persists after the 24-hour suspension.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely hawking their own commercial product and adding no value to the conversation.

Taking action.

Answer (score 0):

He's definitely not from around these parts:

> Notice: You must operate by the order, only support Win2000 and WinXp(32 bit) system now! see "FAQ---how to use it"

What?

Anyway - definitely a spammer, and looks like somebody flagged him already a few hours ago, although a few more couldn't hurt.

Comment: I ran out of flags.